# Repeat action foreach 10 in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array (took from an API) with near 300 values, but I need to call `someAction()` with sets of 10 values. I mean, 1-10, 11-20, 21-30... and so. I was limiting it to 10, but other 290 values were lost. 
Its a multidimensional array.

```
var n = 10; // Limit of names
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    namestr += names[i].first + "(" + names[i].nick + ")";
    if(i != (n-1)){namestr += ", ";}
}
someAction(namest, function(){...});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: There are no multidimensional arrays in Javascript. You mean that it's an array of objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to call someAction on every 10 elements you might do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i+=10) {
    someAction(names.slice(i, i+10));
}
```

Based on your comment, you could do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i+=10) {
    var tmp = names.slice(i, i+10);
    for (var j = 0; j < tmp.length, j++) {
        tmp[j] = tmp[j].first + " (" + tmp[j].nick + ")";
    }
    someAction(tmp.join(","));
}
```

Comment: Not really, what I want is to create a namestr string, with 10 values from the array and then pass this thru someAction; repeating this action until I complete the array.

Comment: Do you really mean `splice`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to cut 10-element chunks from your large array and call your function with it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i += 10) {

   var elements = names.slice(i, i+10);
   // handle this set 
   handleTenItems(elements);
}
```

Or if you just need to handle elements in group of 10:

```
for (var base = 0; base < names.length; base += 10) {

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    namestr += names[base + i].first + "(" + names[base + i].nick + ")";
    if(i != (n-1)){namestr += ", ";}
  }
  someAction(namest, function(){...});
}
```

Side note: I don't see multidimensional array here...

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to the string, and call the method for every 10th item, then call it afterwards with the leftovers:

```
for (var i = 0, namestr = ''; i < names.length; i++) {
  namestr += (namestr.length ? ", " : "") + names[i].first + "(" + names[i].nick + ")";
  if (i % 10 == 9) {
    someAction(namestr, function(){...});
    namestr = '';
  }
}
if (namestr.length) {
  someAction(namestr, function(){...});
}
```